# Using insert and search cursors on same feature class to clone row?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I'm using the code below in order to attempt to clone a row in a feature class and add that same row to the same feature class after updating its metadata (Name, date_start, date_end, etc.)

The problem is that it is duplicating the rows several times, when expecting 2 rows i get 4, expecting 3, getting 8.

```
inFeatureClass  = "C:\TS.gdb\IN_TSGIS"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatureClass, temp_layer_name)
insert_feature_table(temp_layer_name, temp_layer_name, query_single_col('UID',UID), update_fields)

def query_single_col(col, value):
    return '"'+str(col)+'" = ' + str(value)

def insert_feature_table(inputfeatureclass, insertfeatureclass, expr, fields):
     with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(insertfeatureclass, ("*")) as i_cursor:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputfeatureclass, ("*"), where_clause=expr) as s_cursor:
            for s_row in s_cursor:
                i_cursor.insertRow(s_row)
                break
```

Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: Are you interested in overwriting the row values, or adding new rows with the updated values?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use the UpdateCursor instead?

Comment: @Aaron I'm interested in adding new rows with the updated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't possibly be a good idea to use an insert cursor on a feature class while you're in the middle of a search cursor on the same one. I think your search cursor is coming across the rows that had been inserted earlier in the loop, and inserting them *again*, perhaps several times.

My suggestion is to run the search cursor, save the rows to memory, then write them to the table once the search cursor has completed.

```
inFeatureClass = r"C:\TS.gdb\IN_TSGIS"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatureClass, temp_layer_name)
insert_feature_table(temp_layer_name, temp_layer_name, query_single_col('UID',UID), update_fields)

def query_single_col(col, value):
    return '"'+str(col)+'" = ' + str(value)

def insert_feature_table(inputfeatureclass, insertfeatureclass, expr, fields):
    records = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputfeatureclass, ("*"), where_clause=expr) as s_cursor:
        for s_row in s_cursor:
            # Make any changes to the row values you want here
            # e.g. s_row[3] = "some new value"
            records.append(s_row)
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(insertfeatureclass, ("*")) as i_cursor:
        for r in records:
            i_cursor.insertRow(r)
    return None
```